# "Добрий ранок" -"Доброго ранку"

Tags: вибір-слова

Не раз чув як люди говорять і "Доброго ранку!", і "Добрий ранок!" та як правильно і чи є різниця між цими двома варіантами?

В [експрес-уроці](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9tXngTv8ds&vl=uk) української мові кажуть, що єдиним правильним варіантом є "Добрий день/вечір", але потрібно казати **лише "Доброго ранку"**. Причина, чому не можна казати "Доброго дня!" (і, я так розумію, "Добрий ранок") - мовна традиція.

У цьому [джерелі](http://cikavamova.blogspot.com/2017/03/blog-post.html) також вказано, що потрібно казати "Добрий день/вечір", але також вказано, що ми **можемо сказати "Добрий ранок"** (і дається посилання на [Російсько-український словник сталих виразів](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)). Проте тут же є цікава думка автора, тому процитую її:

> Кілька власних міркувань. Зверніть увагу на формули "добридень" і
>   "добривечір": вони застигло вказують на сполуки "добрий день" і
>   "добрий вечір" саме початковій формі, тоді як формули "добриранок" чи
>   подібної не витворено. Може, й через те її нема, що віталися саме
>   "Доброго ранку"?

В Гуглі зустрічається і перший, і другий варіант (а також, я знайшов пісню "Добрий ранок, Україно"). А в перекладі "[Гобіта](https://javalibre.com.ua/java-book/book/2908334)" (не знаю чому, але коли задумався над цим питанням, одразу згадав про цю книгу - ст.7) перекладач використав "Доброго ранку".

Отож, чи справді єдиним можливим варіантом є "Доброго ранку", а "Добрий ранок" - це помилка?

Comment: Маємо подібне запитання: [«Cases for Ukrainian salutations: Доброго ранку vs Добрий ранок; Добрий день vs Доброго дня; Добрий вечір vs Доброго вечора?»](/q/395). Але воно англійською. І крім того, власне тема вранішнього вітання у відповідях майже не розкрита.

Comment: я кажу _добранок_.

Answer (score 3):

На мою думку, слід казати "Доброго ранку", адже раніше цей варіант вживався не як констатація факту (що ранок є добрим), а як побажання (Доброго вам ранку!). Є багато версій та мало пояснень щодо цієї теми, проте ця здається досить логічною. Однак, тоді це викликає сумніви щодо вживання фраз "Добрий день" та "Добрий вечір"

Answer (score 1):

> Отож, чи справді єдиним можливим варіантом є "Доброго ранку", а
>   "Добрий ранок" - це помилка?

**Правильний висновок, так**.

Як і зазначено в [другому запропонованому вами посиланні](http://cikavamova.blogspot.com/2017/03/blog-post.html):

> ...В Україні також переважно говорять "Добрий день!" від самого
>   ранку. Це не помилка. Можна сказати і "Добрий ранок". Але, як сказано
>   у Російсько-українському словнику сталих виразів 1959р. (І. О. Вирган,
>   М. М. Пилинська), у народній мові найчастіше кажуть "Добридень!" уже
>   зранку...

+

> [Останнім часом доволі значного поширення набула форма вітання "Доброго
>   дня!". Багато-хто тепер думає, що українською тільки так і треба
>   вітатися. Очевидно, що ця форма виникла під впливом "Доброго ранку!" і
>   мовці її підхопили тому, що такої форми немає в російській мові.
>   Професор Пономарів жартома каже, що цю форму придумали люди, які
>   "раньше русский преподавали как иностранный, а теперь украинский
>   преподают как родной"](http://cikavamova.blogspot.com/2017/03/blog-post.html)

Сиріч можна казати добрий день. Лиш можу ще одну додати [цитату доктора філологічних наук](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2014/04/140430_ponomariv_blog17_ko):

> Щодо формул вітання я вже неодноразово писав: доброго ранку, добрий
>   день(добридень), добрий вечір (добривечір), добраніч (на добраніч) –
>   це давно усталені формули. Гадаю, їх не варто міняти на штучні:
>   доброго дня, доброго вечора. Так можна казати, коли при цих сполуках
>   маємо ще дієслово: бажаю вам (тобі) доброго дня, доброго вечора.

Які можна зробити висновки? Правильна форма(історична) вітання доброго ранку або добрий день. "Не раз чув як люди говорять" напевно, ви ще довго будете подібне чути, бо в мові обслуговування це не як не регламентується та й пропаганують свідомо неправильні форми/варіанти, а тобто вони можуть стати цілко офіційними... проте це вже інша історія та допоки є усталені форми.

Comment: Також використовую "Раночку" як вітальну форму вранці, напевно вона помилкова, втім набрала певну кількість прихильників.